# Which selector will be used when $(this) is called from an event with multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple selectors in a function with onclick event. And I want to update a global variable based on whichever one is clicked.

```
var sort = '';
$('#firstName, #lastName, #age, #yearLevel, #gender, #event, #year').onclick(function () {
    sort = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Will the `$(this)` use the value of the id which was clicked or all of them?

Question 2:
The ids are for `<a>`, can I use `value` attribute in `<a>`, instead of just getting the id name?

Comment: It will use *the currently clicked element*.  `this` is not a selector, it's an actual DOM node.

Comment: Also, why would you use the `value` attribute? Sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390666/xy-problem-question-and-a-lot-of-upvotes-should-i-change-my-accepted-answer)

Comment: How does this relate to the `value` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `click` instead of `onclick`.

```
var sort = '';
$('#firstName, #lastName, #age, #yearLevel, #gender, #event, #year').click(function () 
{
  sort = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

See Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4mEvS5UE7smOpMFw?open=lib%2Fscript.js

Comment: Instead of `$(this).attr('id')` simpler: `this.id`.